# Can not increase Size of Shared Memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

Could you please help me? I can not increase the size of my Sherd Memory. The code is written in C on Linux.

I need 65536 bytes, but just 49152 seem to be allowed... If I increase it, shmget fails...(in my code: `shmid < 0`)
I tried to find out my maximum shared memory size and increased it with:

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=2147483648
```

But that doesn't help, the initialization again fails.

This is my code:

```
 #define SHM_KEY                 9877

 #define SHM_SIZE                65536

int SHM_init (int shmid, char** shm, key_t key, long int size) {

    /* Create a new (System V) shared memory segment of the specified size */
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0777);

    /* Check if SHM creation was successful */
    if (shmid < 0) {
        /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
        DBG_PRINT("C\n");

        /* Check if creation failed because of already existing SHM */
        if (EEXIST == errno) {
            /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
            DBG_PRINT("CC\n");
            /* Delete already existing SHM with shmctl */
            shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        } else {
            /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
            DBG_PRINT("CCC\n");
        }

        /* Creation and initialization of SHM failed */
        return -1;
    }
    /* Attach the SHM data pointer to the previously created SHM segment */
    *shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if(*shm == (char *) -1) {
        /* Attaching failed */
        return -1;
    }
    DBG_PRINT("Shared Memory Initialization successful\n");
    /* Creation and initialization of shared memory was successful */
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: On failure of `shmget` use `perror`. Read also and prefer using [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). SysV shared memory à la `shmget` might be deprecated and not covered by `kernel.shmmax`

Answer (score 1):

[This topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/371068/shared-memory-shmget-fails-no-space-left-on-device-how-to-increase-limits) might help. 
What does `ipcs -l` return if you increase the shmmax with `sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=2147483648` ?

Comment: ipcs -l returns:

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 32768
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767

------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 992\n
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384